# Why is the Projectile Git repository being set to the most recently cd'd directory?

Tags: git, projectile

When I run `projectile-find-file` in GUI (non-terminal) Emacs, the project directory is set to the directory I most recently `cd`'d to in a terminal window.

Let's say that I have a home directory not under version control, as well as two Git projects, `~/foo` and `~/bar`. If I do the following

1. Open a file in `~/foo` in Emacs.
2. Open a terminal window and run `cd ~/bar`.
3. Run `M-x projectile-find-file`.

it will show me the files in `~/bar`.

And if I `cd` to the home directory in iTerm, I get this message:

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

The expected behavior is that it would show the files in `~/foo` regardless of what directory was most recently `cd`'d into.

When I run `projectile-project-info`, it shows the correct project directory (e.g., `Project dir: /Users/pat/foo ## Project VCS: git ## Project type: emacs-cask`).

I don't know whether this is a bug or I configured something wrong. It used to work correctly. I'm using Emacs 25.1 and Projectile 20160921.902.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was caused by a conflict with the Oh My Zsh plugin [`last-working-dir`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/57fcee0f1c520a7c5e3aa5e2bde974154cdaf0c3/plugins/last-working-dir/last-working-dir.plugin.zsh). Every time you `cd` to a directory, `last-working-dir` saves the path to file. When you open a new terminal window, the plug-in sets the current directory to the value in this file.

The problem is that Emacs runs every shell command as though it were in a new terminal window. You can see this effect by enabling `last-working-dir` and running `(message (shell-command "pwd"))`. If you edit the cache file used by `last-working-dir` and re-run the previous command, it'll output the updated directory.

I don't know of any way of fixing this other than disabling the `last-working-dir`.

Comment: Looking at that script, possibly `(setenv  "ZSH_LAST_WORKING_DIRECTORY" "1")` could help?